# jQuery : Hide select DOM elements created on the fly

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the following code:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    var hideInit = function () {
            $(selector1).hide();
    }
    var loadInit = function () {
            //get data
            var thingo = $('<div />');
            //populate thingo with a bunch of divs matching selector1
            $(selector2).append(thingo);
    }
    loadInit();
    hideInit();
});
```

I am parsing some data and populating the DOM with it in `loadInit`, and then I wish to `.hide` each of the elements present in the DOM that was just created which match `selector1`.

Unfortunately the elements are not being hidden - what have I done wrong here?

Thanks!

---

### Solution

My selectors weren't incorrect, as suggested by many, but it was the order in which I was calling the functions. In order to guarantee that `hideInit` runs after `loadInit` has complete, I call it at the end, inside, of `loadInit`.

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    var hideInit = function () {
            $(selector1).hide();
    }
    var loadInit = function () {
            //get data
            var thingo = $('<div />');
            //populate thingo with a bunch of divs matching selector1
            $(selector2).append(thingo);
            hideInit();
    }
    loadInit();
});
```

Thanks for your comments/ answers!

---

NOT related to : [Using jQUery hide() on newly created dom elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2061430/using-jquery-hide-on-newly-created-dom-elements)

Comment: what happens if you put alert($('selector1').length;); as the first line in hideInit?

Comment: `$('div')` is not a proper constructor, you would need to use `$('<div/>')` to perform that append.

Comment: You mean `var thingo = $('<div>');`, right?

Comment: Maybe you could also give us your html, so we can see what you are trying to do? ;) I don't understand what selector1 and selector2 are. Are those classes? In such case you should prepend with a `.`.

Comment: Please provide some better example... it seems yours leaves open some questions.

Comment: @Esailija : I am, I just have left out the code which does so, and replaced it with this comment, as it is not relevant to the question (I know it is working correctly)

//populate thingo with a bunch of divs matching selector1

Comment: @GustavCarlson : Yes, typo, fixed it above, thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: :) Unfortunately, that definitely means that there's something important we're not seeing here. Does `$('selector1')` in the JS console return what you expect?

Comment: @BonyT : I get 0 (zero) - I do not know why, I can see them all there when I inspect the DOM
@GustavCarlson : Yes it does, it returns all of the expected ones, just not during `hideInit`

Comment: @bguiz: This would be the time to reveal `selector1`.

Comment: Everyone: Solution found, I have edited the question to include this.

Comment: ah - only created in hideInit - mystery solved!
The downvotes are a bit harsh - other than posting the entire application it can be difficult (if you don't know the answer) to post the pertinent bits.

Comment: @BonyT : Yeah, feel the same way about the downvotes - after all, I was merely going for a SSCCE ( http://sscce.org/ )

Comment: Please don't post the solution in the question. Please answer your own answer to this question and post the solution there.

Comment: @AnishGupta : I have accepted Richard's answer, because that led me to the solution. Answering my own question would be counter intuitive after doing so, would it not?

Comment: @bguiz you accepted this after the comment was published

Comment: @AnishGupta : Not to split hairs, but I accepted the solution and added it to my question at `2012-07-06 14:12:37Z`, and you first commented AFTER this, at `2012-07-06 14:27:15Z`, according to the timestamps recorded by Stackoverflow, so this is most certainly not the case.

Comment: @bguiz Really, I could have sworn I had written that earlier. Might have been something to do with my ISP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved with a single line that manipulates the DOM using the `append`, `filter` and `hide` jQuery methods.

1. `$('selector2').append(thingo)` - append the items
2. `.filter('selector1')` - of the original selector, only select those matching the filter
3. `.hide()` - hide the filtered items

Like this:

```
$(function()
{
    var thingo = $('<div />');
    $('selector2').append(thingo).filter('selector1').hide();
}
```

Optionally, if you want to hide the appended items, you'll want to add an additional chain after the `filter`, whereby you could use the `find()` method, like this:

```
// this will hide all child divs, so you may want to be more specific
$('selector2').append(thingo).filter('selector1').find('div').hide();
```

Comment: @ Richard : Yup, this works
The actual solution in my case was to put the call to `hideInit();` at the end of the `loadInit` function, so that it is guranteed to be called sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have something that works. I am not sure though if that is something you try to achieve..Anyway, the example is here: http://jsfiddle.net/dyNbw/

js:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    var hideInit = function () {
            $('.name1').hide();
    }
    var loadInit = function () {
            //get data
            var thingo = $('<div>Hi there</div>');
            //populate thingo with a bunch of divs matching selector1
            $('.name2').append(thingo);
    }
    loadInit();
    hideInit();
});
```

and html:

```
<div class="name1">This will be hidden</div>
<div class="name2"><span>I want to say:</span></div>
```