# what is the difference between loadInit() and onload()?

Tags: jquery

I just wanted to know what is the purpose of using loadInit()? what is the difference between loadInit and onload? are they the same? and is there a difference between onload and onLoad?

Comment: What is `loadInit()`?

Comment: You probably got some demo code somewhere. I see it here too, as a custom function; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11363693/jquery-hide-select-dom-elements-created-on-the-fly

Comment: ok thanks :) cause I saw it some places and I thought it might be something like onload

Answer (score -1, accepted):

please read

init and onload is explained

http://www.elated.com/articles/jquery-getting-started/